# Python NameError 'xxx' not defined when executing a .py script from another .py script

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a script named schedule.py:

```
# Script to schedule and trigger batch run every day of month at 6.30p.m.

from datetime import date
import time
import schedule

def job():
    exec(open("main.py").read())
    print('Batch run completed')
        
schedule.every().day.at("18:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This `schedule.py` will execute the other Python script, `main.py`.

`main.py` is used to process the data, so it involves pandas, numpy.
When I run `main.py` directly, there was no error at all. But when I try to run `main.py` through `schedule.py`, it returns error:

```
NameError: ("name 'np' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')
```

After that, I added

```
import numpy as py
```

into `schedule.py` to solve the error above.

But after solving the `np` not defined error, another error occurs when executing `main.py` through `schedule.py`:

```
NameError: name 'avg_util_l3m' is not defined
```

This variable `avg_util_l3m` is a variable used in `main.py`. The part of `main.py` which uses the variable as below:

```
# lots of code...

avg_util_l3m = joined_df['AverageUtilizationL3M']
avg_util_l3m = joined_df['ProdType'].apply(lambda x: avg_util_l3m if x != 'Non-Revolving' else -9999)

# lots of code...
```

Does anyone know why will this error happen and how do I solve it?

Note:

1. There are no errors at all while running `main.py` directly in cmd. So I think that `np` and `avg_util_l3m` are defined correctly in `main.py`.
2. The full code of `schedule.py` is as above. It does not contain variables like `np` or `avg_util_l3m`. Only `main.py` uses the variables.

Comment: Try to read [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-make-one-Python-file-run-another). I suggest you the first way, i.e. a wrapper function inside `main.py` to call from `schedule.py`

Comment: Don't know if this directly relates to your error, but first thing to do is rename your file. Your file is `schedule.py` and you are importing the `schedule` library... That's a recipe for disaster

Comment: Also you shouldn't run Python files with `exec`... Simply put the relevant code of `main.py` inside a function and call that function directly from `schedule.py`

Comment: Thanks and I'll make changes on the file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in the past and all I can tell you is that exec() is slow and unpredictable, use anything else and I doubt you will have that same error. If your code is too long to simply import, try and use an alternative like runpy.